# Extract Headers from a directory containing multi structure files using Talend

Tags: java, extract, talend

I have a directory where we have multiple files in csv or txt format. I am looking at extracting the header of all the files in a single flow. But the issue is the file structures are different. I would have used `tfilelist-->tfileInputDelimited-->tfileOutputDelimited` if all the files had the same structure and format and limited the flow at 1 to get the headers. But as the strucutures and format is different, I am not able to use the above flow, Is there a way to extract the headers from these files ?
Any help/guidance would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please, check out tExtractRegexFields or tExtractPositionalFields/tExtractDelimitedFields. For the input, you can use a tFileInputFulRow which is schema agnostic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used tFileInputFulRow along with tFileList and have been able to extract the headers column for the files. The only issue I am facing now is that some of the files do not have header columns on the first row, so when I am limiting the row to 1, it is not able to extract the headers from those files. Is there any tweak that I can make to achieve this ?